# Dissolve: Statistics type "most frequent" value of dissolved Polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dissolve

I want to aggregate my features which share a common boundary in ArcGIS. This is easily done using the *Dissolve* Tool in ArcGIS. However, I want to have the attributes of the dissolved polygon based on the attribute occuring most often in this case (see below just a descriptive example). I know that I can dissolve my polygons and then do a *Spatial Join* and there set the *Merge Rule* to *"Mode"*. But why is this not directly possible in the Dissolve-functionality in the *Statistic Type*, do I miss something? Doing this two step approach is quite time consuming, especially when you have very big datasets (*Spatial Join* can compute for long times as we all know).

[image]

Comment: In your left Picture, are "1" one multipolygon or three individual polygons?

Comment: It's three individual polygons

Comment: Perhaps use near to dissolved and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222754/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-select-most-common-value